# Python cron script for windows

Tags: python, windows

I want to always run a Python script in Windows. Every 5 minutes, it is to check if the script is running and if not, run it.

In linux, this can be done using flock and cron job. How can this be done in windows?

Comment: Windows task scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Task scheduler. Create a new basic task with python as the program and your script as the argument.